# Script Cpu usage in Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris

i'm new and in Solaris i'm creating the script bash to save cpu each 5 minuts from 7am to 11pm. When it's 11pm, the script must stop.
i wish that In file the text is so  : 2021-06-26 14:20:00 CPU: 50%

```
PID=$!
sleep 1
now=$(date +%T)

top -c -s 60 -d 60 > /.../cpu.out

if [$now in 11:50:00)]
then
kill $PID 
fi
```

Comment: *creating the script bash to save cpu*  So you're [reinventing SAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/spconcepts-60676.html)?

Comment: As a starting point - copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, and then [edit] your question to replace the current script with the fixed one if you still have a problem.